# How to create a serviceEndpoint via Azure DevOps REST API with an approver or group of approvers?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am using the Azure DevOps REST API to create a serviceendpoint/serviceconnection which works fine. I am using the following endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP

However we would like to specify a group of approvers as you can do via the Azure DevOps portal like shown in the attached image

[image]

Project Settings->Serviceconnections-> Approvals and check

Can this be done via the Azure DevOps REST API?

I reviewed the Microsoft docs with regard to Azure DevOps REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Project Settings->Serviceconnections-> Approvals and check Can this be done via the Azure DevOps REST API?

Yes. We can achieve this via Rest API.

You can use the Rest API: [Check Configurations - Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/check-configurations/add?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) to add approvers to service endpoint.

Here is an example:

**API URL:**

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/checks/configurations?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

**Request Body:**

```
{
    "type":{
        "id":"8C6F20A7-A545-4486-9777-F762FAFE0D4D",
        "name":"Approval"
        },
    "settings":{
        "approvers":[{
            "displayName":"UserName",
            "id":"UserID",
            "uniqueName":"emailaddress"
           }],
        "executionOrder":1,
        "minRequiredApprovers":0,
        "requesterCannotBeApprover":false},
    "resource":{
        "type":"endpoint",
        "id":"ServiceEndpointID"
    
        },
    "timeout":43200
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have not tried this myself, but a little reverse engineering of the Azure DevOps  UI leads me to believe there is a generic API object for checks and approvals used by various object types within ADO.

I think [Check Configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/check-configurations?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) API for approvals and checks is what you need. This does use version 7.1 of the API though.